# Did original Vedic marriage have only 4 times going around the fire?

Tags: rituals, marriage

In today's times in vedic vivah , the bride and groom together move around the fire 7 times (Saat-Phere). (Though in Gujarat and Sindhi community , there are 4 Pheras)

But I have heard some people saying that the original vedic viah had [only 4 times going around the fire .](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-sometimes-only-4-steps-instead-of-7-of-Saptapadi-in-Hindu-marriage/answer/Harsh-Patel-295) and it is the number of steps that is 7.  The four rounds denotes 4 purusarth - Dharma, Artha, Kaam and Moksha .It looks logical as man and woman marry to do four purusarth of life together.
Also the sanskrit word Saptapadi means - Seven steps and not Seven rounds.
How true it is ?

[Bageshwar Dham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tT8sJjy-r0) telling only 4 Pheras are there

[Another Pandit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tT8sJjy-r0) telling only 4 Pheras

Comment: @Adiyarkku [4 rounds and 7 steps](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-there-sometimes-only-4-steps-instead-of-7-of-Saptapadi-in-Hindu-marriage/answer/Harsh-Patel-295)

Comment: So thae above linked question is the answer to your question.